# Should I use mysql_upgrade after mysqld_safe when upgrading MariaDB?

Tags: best-practices, upgrade, mariadb

I'm wanting to know the best practice to do a MariaDB upgrade on opensuse.

I am getting this error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db =
'a_database'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably
corrupted (1548)
```

I'm assuming that an upgrade will fix the error.

So what is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade versions, run the upgrade script.  Often there are new columns in various system tables.